# How do you hibernate on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, power-management, hibernate, acpi

I searched this online but all articles found are outdated. What should I do to enable hibernation in GNOME?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### To enable Hibernation in 20.04:

**Increase swapfile size to match RAM size up to 8GB.**

- Check the swap that is in use:

  `sudo swapon -s`
- If swap partition(s) found:

  `sudo swapoff -a`

  `sudo nano -Bw /etc/fstab`
- Add "# " before the UUID of the swap partition(s):

  `# UUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX   none   swap    sw     0       0`
- Add a line for the swapfile, if one does not exist:

  `swapfile   none    swap     sw      0       0`
- Create the swap file:

  `sudo fallocate -l XG /swapfile`*

Where X is the swapfile size in GB

```
    sudo mkswap /swapfile

    sudo chmod 0600 /swapfile

    sudo swapon /swapfile
```

- Reboot:

  `sudo reboot`

**Add resume location and offset to grub.cfg:**

- Edit /etc/default/grub:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX resume_offset=XXXXX"`

- Use UUID from root.
- Use offset from `sudo filefrag -v /swapfile |grep " 0:"| awk '{print $4}'`
- Update GRUB
  `sudo update-grub`
- Test hibernation
  `sudo systemctl hibernate`

A hibernate button can be added using gnome extensions. https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/755/hibernate-status-button/

*There is a slight possibility of getting holes in a swapfile when creating it with fallocate. /var/log/syslog can be searched for the phrase `swapon: swapfile has holes` to ensure there will be no data loss.

A swapfile can alternatively be created using dd: `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1G count=8` **An error when using dd may overwrite your HDD**

Comment: Can I resize the swap partition instead of using a swap file?

Comment: for grub cfg, can I use my ESP as I am booting with UEFI?

Comment: can I delete the swap partition?

Comment: @NinePlusTenEqualsTwentyOne Yes, you can resize your swap partition instead of using a swap file, or delete it or use both a swapfile and swap partition. 20.04 makes it's own swapfile, (you may already be using both). Add UUID and offset to your grub.cfg it will find it's way to a UEFI boot.

Comment: how do you resize a LVM partition?

Comment: With LVM I have only managed to resize my swapfile. People have told me that it is easy to resize a LVM partition, but they have never explained how, at least not so I could understand.

Comment: `chown` is wrong. it must be chmod.

Comment: @pooria: I tested the above quite a few times and could have sworn chown worked for me, but I must have been typing chmod.as that seems to be the normal method, Thanks above has been edited.

Comment: That answer enables hibernation from the OS. What about the Gnome menu?

Comment: @Hiran Chaudhuri, You can add a hibernation button using **Gnome-Extensions**

Comment: From my POV this should be part of the answer, as it was part of the question as well. But I will search how to install gnome extensions (and actually the right one) via command line somehow.

Comment: @Hiran Chaudhuri; Thank you, I have added a link to Gnome-Hibernate Status Button. https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/755/hibernate-status-button/