# Sleep / hibernating is not working on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: 20.10

I am using Ubuntu 20.10 in my laptop. I tried to use sleep mode, so that I can come back to avoid boot the system again. when I come again and wake up the system, it gives only prompt in the screen and the system is not getting boot up to login screen. I need to restart the system again to login in to the Ubuntu. I don't know how to fix the problem. please guide me and thanks in advance.

Comment: look at my question maybe it will help you https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285207/how-do-you-hibernate-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: also sleep and hibernate are two different things

Comment: Hibernatin is different on later versions of Ubuntu that use swapfiles and not swap partitions. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285207/how-do-you-hibernate-on-ubuntu-20-04