# Ubuntu stuck at HP logo after trying to setup swapfile for hibernation

Tags: boot, swap, hibernate

I use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS which I installed dual boot to Windows. I wanted to add Hibernation as an option. So I installed pm utilities and tried `sudo pm-hibernate` It did not work. I read somewhere that the swap file should be equal to the size of my RAM. My RAM is 8 GB and my swap file was 1.4 GB (default). I hadn't tampered with anything earlier when I had installed Ubuntu.

Then after looking up, I followed [THIS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285207/how-do-you-hibernate-on-ubuntu-20-04). And I did everything exactly up until about 7 steps where it says to "reboot".

Steps include - doing `swapoff -a`, adding a # against a UUID in the existing swap file. Creating an 8GB swap file using `sudo fallocate -l 8G /swapfile`

```
sudo mkswap /swapfile

sudo chmod 0600 /swapfile

sudo swapon /swapfile
```

And then I hit reboot. Then it boots to get stuck at HP logo (Ubuntu at the bottom). I tried hard shud down and booting again. It again gets frozen at HP logo.

Did mess anything up? How do I go ahead and fix this?

P.S - I must mention that there were 3 UUID's in the file. I didnt know which one to add a # to. Then I looked up how search for my UUID of the swap file and found my UUID and then hashed only that one.

Comment: a suggestion: `chroot` into the system using a live usb with linux and restore `fstab` to previous state

Comment: @Andra  Alright, I did that. Thanks!

I went to recovery mode and removed the # from the fstab. Now the swapfile says it's 8GB but it still shuts down, instead of hibernate.

Comment: did you edit `grub` and add `resume`?

Comment: @Andra , Yes. I had. But when I booted back, nothing I was doing was saved. But this ( https://askubuntu.com/a/1321773/1601559 ) answer fixed everything. Got hibernate working now!!