# How to fix swapfile problem having holes - Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, swap

I have created a swapfile successfully, but when I am trying to:

```
"sudo swapon /swapfile"
```

this is what I see:

```
"swapon: /swapfile1: skipping"
```

It appears to **have holes**.

How can I create a swapfile that doesn't have a hole?

Comment: So how exactly did you create the swapfile?

Comment: @steeldriver: Some people have had a problem with holes when using fallocate to create swapfiles. https://askubuntu.com/a/1285218/43926 `sudo fallocate -l XG /swapfile`

Comment: @C.S.Cameron hence my question ;)

Comment: @steeldriver: I only know of two methods to create a swapfile, one is `fallocate` the other is `dd`. `Fallocate` is known to occasionally create holes, `dd` is not. The method using fallocate is given above in my comment, and the method using dd is given in my answer below. Do you have a preferred method to create swapfiles not mentioned?  The OP has not confirmed their method.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron I know far less about it than you - I've upvoted your answer, but unless the OP engages we're spinning our wheels

Answer (score 2):

### Swapfile Holes

There is a slight possibility of getting holes in a swapfile when creating it with **fallocate**.

`/var/log/syslog` can be searched for the phrase `swapon: swapfile has holes` to ensure there will be no data loss.

A swap file can alternatively be created using dd:

`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1G count=8`

**An error when using dd may overwrite your HDD.**

Comment: I am still having the same problem, i tried using both fallocate and dd ...... still getting the error saying there is holes